# How to make Accuracy-Precision Graphic

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I make a graphic like this:
[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! we  normally not offer servide "do-it-for-me", so please show us what you try so far and where you stuck in your efforts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think of this as a "welcome to TeX.SE!" present.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\draw[latex-latex,thick](0,-9) -- node[midway,sloped,above] {Increasing precision}
(0,0) -- node[midway,sloped,above] {Increasing accuracy} (9,0);
%
\begin{scope}[shift={(2.5,-2.25)}]
 \foreach \X in {0.25,0.75,1.25,1.75}
 {\draw (0,0) circle (\X);}
 \node[anchor=north] at (-90:1.8) {(a)};
 \foreach \X in {1,...,12}
  \fill (-1,1) + (rand*360:rand*1) circle(2pt);
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[shift={(7.5,-2.25)}]
 \foreach \X in {0.25,0.75,1.25,1.75}
 {\draw (0,0) circle (\X);}
 \node[anchor=north] at (-90:1.8) {(b)};
 \foreach \X in {1,...,12}
  \fill  (rand*360:rand*1) circle(2pt);
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[shift={(2.5,-7)}]
 \foreach \X in {0.25,0.75,1.25,1.75}
 {\draw (0,0) circle (\X);}
 \node[anchor=north] at (-90:1.8) {(c)};
 \foreach \X in {1,...,12}
  \fill (-1,1) + (rand*360:rand*0.5) circle(2pt);
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[shift={(7.5,-7)}]
 \foreach \X in {0.25,0.75,1.25,1.75}
 {\draw (0,0) circle (\X);}
 \node[anchor=north] at (-90:1.8) {(d)};
 \foreach \X in {1,...,12}
  \fill  (rand*360:rand*0.5) circle(2pt);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Woah! Awesome! I have a question. Is there any environment where you do the graphics? I have seen other forums and they make it look very easy.

Comment: @toborochi I am sorry, I do not understand your question. I am using the LaTeX environment `tikzpicture` here.

Comment: Is there a program that you use to make the graph? you make it look so easy.

Comment: @toborochi Yes. This is a LaTeX site. So I compile with latex, to be specific, I used `pdflatex` for this, but `xelatex` or `lualatex` will work, too. Otherwise it's just a simple text editor and marmot claws. ;-)